# Excel VBA Retrieve cell value in string even if cell is N/A, REF and other

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I am trying to retrieve the value of a cell in VBA, and would like an empty string if the cell value cannot be interpreted. Some cells have `#REF!` some have `#N/A` and other weird "values" which stop the VBA code when I try to assign to a string.

I have an `On Error GoTo label_error_1` but for some reason it does not always work.

Comment: You will need to post the relevant code for use to help, but something using `IfError()` would probably work.

Answer (score 0):

The function `IfError()` does the job.